# Select audio from external storage corona sdk

Tags: audio, coronasdk

I have to select audio file from device storage.it is possible in corona SDK.Any other solution for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this that works fine ans shows me all the lines in that file:

```
log = "/sdcard/coordinates1.txt" -- sdcard
function listfiles ()

 local doc_path = system.pathForFile( log)
 i=1
 for file in lfs.dir(doc_path) do
    i = i+1
 ycort = display.newText ( file, 80, 280+i*10, native.systemFont, 12)

 end
end
```